# App bar overlapping settings in Android activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have followed the official Android documentation on [how to create a settings activity using a fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), but I got this result:

[image]

I have tried setting a top margin to the settings contents but that didn't change the result, the settings would still end up below the app bar as you can see in the picture.

So, this are the relevant parts of my code:

**My settings activity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Display the settings fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();


    }

}
```

Nothing fancy here, I just load the layout file and insert the fragment with the list of settings.

**The settings fragment**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

Again, nothing fancy, I simply load the preferences from their XML file.

**The settings activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mydomain.myapp.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_settings" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The settings activity content layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mydomain.myapp.SettingsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_settings">

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is empty for now as I am loading everything from the XML preferences file anyway.

How can I make sure that the content of my settings activity ends up right below the activity's app bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an id to your `RelativeLayout` and use that as the id in your `FragmentManager.replace`. This makes it use the `RelativeLayout` for you fragment container instead of the whole system window.